# drupal module development

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

i have 2 question in drupal:
1.what's means of vid in node table?
2.I have three vocabularies:
Embassy
Organisation
Bussiness
How can I test in my node-address.tpl.php if the node type address belongs Embassy vocabulary ?

Comment: Do you know that there is a drupal q+a site as well [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Node revision ID
2. I would use hook_node_view() for D7 or hook_nodeapi() `"view"` `$op` in a case of D6 for this. Putting logic into a template file is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

vid depends on context, it can either mean Vocabulary ID in taxonamy or reVision ID for nodes. In the latter case it only is used if you have revisions enabled and it is set to save older versions of nodes.